# ListBox wpf SelectItem как получить в коде

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

```
ListBox lBox = new ListBox();
lBox.Items.Add("asdasd");
lBox.Items.Add("ыва23");
nb.Children.Add(lBox);
```

Как получить выделенный Item из списка?

Comment: Для WPF нужно внутри вьюхи добавить публичное свойство `SelectedItem` и связать его с боксом.

Comment: `lBox.SelectedItem` же

Comment: @Андрей видимо человек использует MVVM

Comment: @Сергей, по коду в вопросе вроде же видно, что не использует

Comment: @Андрей тогда и WF достаточно. WPF тут не нужен.

Comment: Уточните вопрос - с каким проектом работаете ?

Comment: @Сергей, ну это уже не нам решать

Comment: @Сергей с  WPF работаю

Comment: @fangry, дополнил ответ, посмотрите, может подойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx), например:

```
MessageBox.Show((string)lBox.SelectedItem);
```

---

Для того, чтобы отслеживать смену текущего элемента, подпишитесь на событие `SelectionChanged`:

```
lBox.SelectionChanged += lBox_SelectionChanged;
```

пример обработчика:

```
private void lBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)lBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, немного поменял код, но в целом помог

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не используете WPF и MVVM то применяйте решение, которое дал уважаемый @Андрей. Если же все же используете то поступайте так :

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItemcColllections}" Margin="0,65,0,150"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Событие при загрузке формы :

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

Сам класс вьюмодели :

```
 class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListBoxItemcColllections { get; set; }
    private string selectedItem { get; set; }


    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ListBoxItemcColllections = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ListBoxItemcColllections.Add("111");
        ListBoxItemcColllections.Add("222");
        ListBoxItemcColllections.Add("333");
    }
}
```

Результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать динамическое добавления n-го кол-ва списков. И необходимо по нажатие на какой-то элемент из списка, получить его.

Comment: @fangry вы работаете с Code-bechind или MVVM?

Comment: наверное в MVVM, я не совсем понимаю о чем вы. в Visual Studio просто создал проект WPF.

Comment: @fangry MVVM это паттерн по которому строятся сложные пользовательские интерфейсы. Например, вы открываете проект WinForms - добавляете кнопку, и делаете 2й клик на нее после этого автоматически добавится событие вида `private void onbutton_clic(...){}` так вот - это Code bechind. Решение Андрея подходит, если же вы создаете вью модель то это MVVM.

Comment: Решение Андрея не подходит, т.к, когда выбираю другой элемент ничего не происходит

Comment: @fangry добавьте полный код в вопрос

Comment: @fangry `Решение Андрея не подходит, т.к, когда выбираю другой элемент ничего не происходит` Не происходит где???? И что должно происходить-то?